# Does a fluid with $0$ divergence have $0$ density?

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm starting a course on Vector Calculus, and I got to the intuitive relation between the divergence and the density of the fluid, namely that we can see the divergence as the opposite of the change of density per unit of time, or:

$$div(F)=-\frac{d\rho}{dt}$$

where $F$ is the vector field, and $\rho$ is the density of the fluid, both functions of position and time.

From this, we deduce that given the divergence, we can compute the density by integrating the divergence with respect to the time. Now, if the field $F$ does **not** depend on the position, e.g., $F(x,y,t)=(t,t+1)$, then the divergence is $0$, which by the above formula would imply the density is also $0$.

This seems rather counterintuitive to me, as the fluid does seem to be increasing in quantity as time passes, yet the density is $0$? Care to help me understand this?

Comment: If $\mathrm d\rho/\mathrm dt=0$, it doesn't mean that $\rho=0$. It just means that $\rho$ is constant. (Everyone forgets the constant of integration, grumble grumble...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\rho$ isn't $0$, $\frac{d\rho}{dt}=0$. That means that density is constant and not necessarily $0$.

Comment: Ah jeez, that's right, dumb me. So, if the density is constant, how can we interpret that? If the vector field is, say, $F(x,y,t)=(t,t+1)$ as in my example above, and the density is constant, does that mean the fluid is just moving at the same rate on every point of the plane, and increasing that rate as time passes by?

Comment: If the density is constant, it means that the fluid is incompressible.